# Why is my table not scrolling in my card?

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerview that has a variable number of cards.  Each card represents a meal, and has a table with a variable number of foods.  I'm trying to get my tables to scroll, but I'm not having any luck.

I've tried dropping everything but the scrollview, giving the scrollview different weights, with or without a LinearLayout as a parent to the TableLayout.  Nothing worked.

Here's my current layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="cards main container">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabAddFood"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/foodTable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="0dp">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#0079D6">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvFood"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp8"
                            android:text="@string/food"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvQty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp16"
                            android:text="@string/hashtag"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there something wrong with scrolling inside a card?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have a `FloatingActionButton` inside a `CardView`? I can't say I've seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `layout_weight`. Make your child view's height/width `0dp` according to the orientation of parent view to serve the purpose. Just a note if your parent view has two child views with same weight. setting `layout_weight` with a larger number doesn't make any difference. It calculates the between the weights.

- horizontal -> `layout_width="0dp"`
- vertical -> `layout_height="0dp"`

  ```
   <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:baselineAligned="false">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_height="0dp"  // make it 0 dp
              android:orientation="vertical"/>

          <ScrollView
             android:layout_width="0dp" //it should be 0dp
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:isScrollContainer="true"
             android:layout_weight="2"/>
  ```

Comment: Have you tried this?  I'm afraid it didn't help, but it did complain that a LinearLayout needs a layout_height.

Comment: yeah provide a height, I edited it upon your code, where weight issue caught my eye, and based on that i provided the above answer.  Check I've added the height

Comment: The ScrollView still isn't scrolling for me.  Any reason the second LinearLayout needs to have 0dp height if the ScrollView's outside it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your root linearlayout to match_parent. With wrap_content enabled its likely expanding off the screen eliminating the scrollbar in the recyclerview.

Comment: Thanks, but when I change the root linearlayout to layout_height:match_parent, I only see one card at a time.  Not what I wanted.